# How to download video flash from Qhonline ?

Tags: javascript, flash

I am facing a problem/challenge on figure out the way to scrape/download the video from flash with encoded to prevent user to download the content. Please review the link below for an example: http://www.qhonline.edu.vn/video-training16a2785255z725.html

I did various researches on multiple sources, but till haven't found any solutions yet. Thus, any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.